# SQLJ в Java (Intellij idea)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Подскажите, какую библиотеку нужно скачать, или нечто подобное, чтобы работало

```
import oracle.sqlj.runtime.*;
```

[image: import oracle.sqlj.runtime.*]

Comment: Какая база данный?

Comment: @RomanC Тут использую Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) находится все для БД Oracle. Библиотеки находятся в инсталляционной директории с назавнием sqlj.

Требования к использованию реализации Oracle SQLJ

Для использования реализации Oracle SQLJ необходимы:

```
 Система базы данных, доступная с помощью драйвера JDBC

 Файлы классов для SQLJ-переводчика

 Связанные с переводчиком классы доступны в следующем файле:

 ORACLE_HOME / SQLJ / Библиотека / translator.jar

 Заметка:
 Для получения дополнительной информации о translator.jar см. «Установить путь и путь к классам».

 Файлы классов для времени выполнения SQLJ.

 ORACLE_HOME / SQLJ / Библиотека / runtime12.jar

 Заметка:
 runtime12ee.jar устарел с момента выпуска Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1). Вместо этого используйте runtime12.jar.
```

Comment: спасибо большое.